# how to replace Image in Lottie animation at runtime in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

iOS: I am unable to dynamically change only a specific image in my JSON file. People recommend using BundleImageProvider but it's of no use because there is no way to provide the key for which I want to replace the image.

the android counterpart for the same is updateBitmap but can't find anything in iOS.

Comment: I'd go with using a custom AnimationImageProvider https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios/blob/master/lottie-swift/src/Public/ImageProvider/AnimationImageProvider.swift I used it in my project to load image from XCAssets.

Comment: @Larme how to fetch the image in the DocumentsDirectory

Comment: With `FileManager` and `Data` to get a `UIImage`, then convert it into a `CGImage`?

Comment: @Larme I did the same but don't show an image

Comment: What's your code? Is your code even called? How can we tell what's wrong?

Comment: @TanjimaKothiya got any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
before start new animation - `.pause()`

`YourAnimation.animation = Animation.named(newAnimationJsonName)`

after change animation - `.play()`